# javac "cannot find symbol" error with command line

Tags: java, javac

I have two classes Owning and OwningAccessor. The files are in the same directory.

```
public class Owning {
    String _name = "";
    public void printBanner()
    {
    }
    public void printOwning(double amount)
    {
        printBanner();

        //print details
        System.out.println("name:" + _name);
        System.out.println("amount:" + amount);
    }
}


public class OwningAccessor {
    public void access()
    {
        Owning o = new Owning();
        o.printOwning(500);
    }
}
```

When I tried to compile `OwningAccessor` with `javac -cp . OwningAccessor.java`, I got compilation error.

```
symbol  : class Owning
location: class smcho.OwningAccessor
        Owning o = new Owning();
        ^
OwningAccessor.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Owning
location: class smcho.OwningAccessor
        Owning o = new Owning();
                   ^
```

What's wrong with this? The code compiles fine under eclipse IDE.

Comment: are they in the same directory? Show your source path directory structure

Comment: They are in the same directory.

Comment: No repro, works here. Does it work if you first compile `Owning.java`?

Comment: Don't you need a `this` in there somewhere?

Comment: @Daniel: No, it doesn't work even I compile the Owning.java to get class file.

Comment: And what if you remove the `-cp .`? Wouldn't be needed for files in the current directory anyway.

Comment: @Daniel : Same error without `-cp .`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, let's suppose you have the code distributed in files as follows

```
myproject
├── out
└── src
    ├── OwningAccessor.java
    └── Owning.java
```

Go to your command prompt, and change directory to `myproject`. Once there issue the following command:

```
javac -d out -sourcepath src src/OwningAccessor.java
```

I just tested it and it works just fine. Your compiled classes will be located in the `out` folder:

```
.
├── out
│   ├── OwningAccessor.class
│   └── Owning.class
└── src
    ├── OwningAccessor.java
    └── Owning.java
```

Compiling one class will trigger the compilation of all other dependent classes. The compiler will automatically look for them in the `src` folder.

Comment: this just complies the program, i wonder why I am not getting output of systme.out.print in CMD ?

Comment: Best way is to create a jar it will take care of all this and is fairly simple.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you compile both Owning.java and OwningAccessor.java, like so:

`javac -cp . Owning.java OwningAccessor.java`

Eclipse compiles all necessary files for you, which is why does work there.

Comment: Doesn't java figure out dependencies on its own?

Comment: It does if you use the `-sourcepath` flag in your compiler

Comment: Sourcepath should do the trick, unfortunately I cannot test it as javac on my machine crashes with an ACCESS_VIOLATION on anything I try to compile...

Comment: @Kninnug: -sourcepath doesn't work. I don't see reason why compilation all the source at once works whereas one by one does not.

Comment: Well, like I said, I can't test it right now (except in Eclipse, which is what we don't want). But apparently javac doesn't look for the necessary files by itself. You could also enter `javac -cp . *.java` which should compile all the .java files in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a correct sourcepath example:

```
javac -d temp -sourcepath c:\awork\JavaProjects\singleton\src\ c:\JavaProjects\singleton\src\com\company\MySingleton.java

javac -d temp -sourcepath c:\awork\JavaProjects\singleton\src\ c:\JavaProjects\singleton\src\com\company\Main.java
```

In "temp" we alocate resources and with **-sourcepath** indicate where are the .java files.

Answer (score 0):

So, in a directory named D:\Automation there is a file Demo.java throwing this error, in cmd while you are in D:\Automation, you need to : -
1) cd.. //will pull you out from Automation directory.
In D:> 2) javac Automation\Demo.java

this will compile your file - Demo.java