# Name not found error in java

Tags: java

My first class.(*named Person.java*)

```
public class Person {
 // Instance variables
 private String name;
 private String address;
 // Constructor
 public Person(String name, String address) {
 this.name = name;
 this.address = address;
 }
 // Getters
 public String getName() {
 return this.name;
 }
 public String getAddress() {
 return this.address;
 }
 public String toString() {
 return this.name + "(" + this.address + ")";
 }
}
```

My second class.(*named Student.java*)

```
public class Student extends Person {
// Instance variables
private String subject;
// Constructor
public Student(String name, String adress, String subject){
    super(name, adress);
    this.subject = subject  
}
// getters
public String getSubject(){
    return this.subject ;
}

}
```

My class that uses those two classes.(run method is like the main)

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Test extends Program{

   public void run() {
      Student obj1 = new Student("Kwnstantinos", "Liakataiwn", "math");
}
}
```

I am writing the following in the cmd to compile it but I got **cannot find symbol** error in compilation.

```
javac -cp acm.jar Person.java Student.java Test.java
```

I tried to make an Person's class object and it worked but when I am trying to create a Student's class object I get this error.Why is this happening.

```
C:\Users\Kwnstantinos\Desktop\JAVA>javac -cp acm.jar Person.java Student.java Test.java
Test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
      Student obj1 = new Student("Kwnstantinos", "Liakataiwn", "math");
      ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Test
Test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
      Student obj1 = new Student("Kwnstantinos", "Liakataiwn", "math");
                         ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Test
2 errors
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include the full error message you are getting?

Comment: You post with new Student and your error is with Teacher, something is wrong here

Comment: Wait that's because I was playing with the code.I uploaded a photo with the full error message I hope it will help you.

Comment: Don't use images, please. Copy the error as text

Comment: Possible duplicate. Refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407983/javac-cannot-find-symbol-error-with-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407983/javac-cannot-find-symbol-error-with-command-line)

Comment: My answer would work on Linux. Windows uses semicolons. `javac -cp ".;acm.jar;`

Comment: In any case, if you want to learn Java more quickly, start with an IDE

Comment: Okay guys I found what the problem was.
The problem was not in the command line but it was that I had create the student's class in another folder and it could not find it at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not imported the Student class in the Test class, and these two classes Test.java and Student.java are in different packages.

This line needs to have a semicolon at the end

```
this.subject = subject;
```

After that its compiling fine without the jar import.

Yes the other answer was correct you need to have it like this

`javac -cp . Person.java Student.java Test.java` if you remove the acm from the import

and they are compiling fine.

Comment: I have all these 3 java files in the same folder.
So what should I write in the import statement?

Comment: Ok that is fine. Are they in the same package too?

Comment: By being in the same folder, they should by definition be in the same package

Comment: Might be the package statement is given in them

Comment: I didn't use any package statements

Comment: Then the question has left out the package line for an unknown reason but left in the other import statements? You don't need an import when they're  in the same package

Comment: There is no error in this code it is all compiling successfully.

Comment: Only one semicolon was missing otherwise all the three classes has compiled successfully on my machine. I have put the line in the answer.